# How can I strictly grep for 2 periods(.)?

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have a list of domains, however some duplicated in the form of for for example:

```
    boy.or.uk
    man.me.uk
    admin.man.me.uk
    root.man.me.uk
    girl.co.uk
    woman.co.uk
    mail.woman.co.uk
    www.woman.co.uk
    youtube.co.uk
```

You can see woman.co.uk and man.me.uk occurs multiple times. I'd like to filter it out and remain with just.

```
    boy.or.uk
    man.me.uk
    girl.co.uk
    woman.co.uk
    youtube.co.uk
```

This is the closest I've managed to get to an [answer](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1278313). The problem with this that it includes everything with two periods and above.  I'm basically looking for a bash one liner of making sure the line ends with .uk and also filters out the subdomain or one that greps for strictly 2 periods. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sed and BRE:

```
sed 's/^\( *\).*\.\(.*\..*\.\uk)/\1\2/' file | sort -u
```

**Edit:**

Added the `.uk` filter.

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with something like this:

```
grep -E "^([^.]+\.){2}uk$" <infile> | sort -u
```

The `grep -E` regex will match only lines with 3 words separated by two periods that end in `uk`, and `sort -u` will ensure uniqueness.

Comment: also add `^[^.]+\.[^.]+\.uk$` as OP also mentioned `making sure the line ends with .uk` in question details

Comment: Should the period inside the brackets be escaped  [^\.] ?

Comment: No, it's fine in the character class - `[.]` means "literal period character", so, quite naturally, `[^.]` means "anything that isn't a literal period character".

Answer (score 1):

You could use awk instead:

```
awk -F'.' '(NF==3) && ($NF=="uk")' file
```

The above ensures there's 3 `.`-separated strings (as would occur given 2 `.`s in the input) and the last one is `uk`. If you want to ensure uniqueness that's just an additional tweak:

```
awk -F'.' '(NF==3) && ($NF=="uk") && !seen[$0]++' file
```

Comment: Had the input contained a line `csc.cam.ac.uk` this would not print that.. Perhaps that is the requirement as the op said  `or one that greps for strictly 2 periods.` But  I'm not sure this is what they intended to do.

Comment: Yes, that is precisely the requirement, to only print lines containing exactly 2 periods and ending in `uk`. See the expected output in the OPs question.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Out of curiosity how would you go about @sjsam requirement ie if the list had contained `csc.cam.ac.uk` and you wanted to have `cam.ac.uk` in the result?

Comment: That all depends what the requirement is that causes that transformation and what your full set of possible input can like but something like `awk -F'.' '{$0=gensub(/.*(([^.]+\.){2}[^.]+)$/,"\\1",1)} (NF==3) && ($NF=="uk") && !seen[$0]++' file` MIGHT be what you want. That uses GNU awk for gensub().